# .htaccess ip-based redirect WILL NOT work for me

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I really have no idea what the deal is here. I've tried every variation I can find an example of and not a single one works.

Here is my current code:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XXX\.XX\.XXX$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/forum [R=302,L]
```

I've tried everything I can find and still, nothing.

What I'm trying to do is redirect everyone except myself to the forum directory of the site. What it is doing is redirecting everyone, myself included, to the forum directory when trying to access the index page. I want to redirect everyone to the forum directory because I'm adding new non-forum features that I don't want anyone else to have access to. The IP I've entered matches the IP that I got from whatismyip.com. Is it possible that the IP address given to me is wrong? Is there a more reliable way to get an IP address? I assumed this was accurate.

Answer (score 0):

[Update]

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^XX\.XXX\.XX\.XXX$
RewriteRule !^forum(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/forum [R,L]
```

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. That gave everyone access to the main page.

Comment: The problem changed from everyone (including me) being redirected to /forum to no one being redirected to /forum.

Comment: OK, I think the better way is not about Redirection. I think what you need right now is Basic Authentication. You can create generate .htaccess for basic authentication by following url [link](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/)

Comment: That looks like it will deny everyone from accessing the forum directory except for myself.

Comment: So, is that not what you want in the problem statement? I am so confuse right now, sorry for that.

Comment: I want everyone to have access to /forum but only one IP, mine, to have access to the main directory.